# ANTLR for parsing calculation in JSON format

Tags: json.net, antlr4

I am new to ANTLR and trying to see if ANTLR fit into my scenario or I should stick to JSON deserialization library and write some custom code.

1. Input text is a JSON which represents an expression like

   ```
   {
   "Operator":"ADD",
   "Operands": [{"Operator":"ADD", "Operands":[{"OperandValue":23},{"OperandValue":32} ]},
            {"Operator":"ADD", "Operands":[{"OperandValue":11},{"OperandValue":12} ]}]}
   }
   ```
2. list of Operators can evolve
3. JSON is created programmatically and not manually created by users by hand.
4. I have to read this JSON and validate it and give meaningful error messages to my client.
5. If JSON in valid/parsed, I have to  translate JSON  to TSQL code and execute on SQL server.

All my code will be in C# and I need:

1. max Debug support and ease
2. unit testability
3. less custom code
4. min. learning

With above two needs, I tried to write a rough ANTLR grammar and custom code and below are my observation

1. ANTLR in a way my logic will reside grammar file, which might be difficult to

   - debug writing grammar for new comer. and unit test. for doing my grammar POC I was relying only `context.GetText()` property to figure out where I am currently and change my grammar.
   - I have to write a modularized grammar(building blocks), so that I can have visitor for my smallest part and more manageable visitor class.
   - How can I give more meaning full messages to my clients, with them having least knowledge of my grammar parsing engine?
2. custom JSON deserialization (JSON.NET)

   - code easy to debug, and everyone understands. I get a JSON reader and write condition to check if JSON Object or JsonArray and if it has Property Operator with value ADD and similar.
   - custom code I can give more meaningful validation failure messages.

To me ANTLR seems to have high value when your input is not highly structured and you don't have available parsers, but in case of JSON it doesn't give much value add over JSON parsers.

Is ANTLR meant for this scenario?

Comment: JSON parsing is a *solved* problem, just use Json.Net, as ANTLR would only help you in the parsing stage, so there's nothing to gain from it. It's useful when you have a custom language (which BTW is *structured* unlike you said).